# VBScritp esperar um processo finalizar e começar outro sem Sleep

Tags: vbs, vbscript

estou com o seguinte problema montei um VBScritp para automatizar alguns processos, estou utilizando Sleep para que ele aguarde um processo terminar para iniciar outro, mas muitas vezes o tempo é variável e pode demorar mais ou menos do que eu defini, queria que fosse mais automático assim que terminasse um processo iniciasse outro já identificando que o outro terminou, sabem se isso é possível com VBS? Se não tem alguma linguagem que isso possa ser possível ? Obrigado a todos

Comment: Deu tudo certo, muito obrigado pela sua ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Use o método "Run" do Objeto Shell, com as propriedades ajustadas de acordo.
Veja o código abaixo:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """C:\Program Files\ABC\abc.xex""", 0, True
```

O 1º argumento é o caminho do executável (ou script vbs).

O segredo é o 3º argumento, se for True, vai esperar o comando acabar para só então continuar para a próxima linha, sem precisar usar Sleep(), na prática uma chamada síncrona.
Se você definir como False, já continua imediatamente a execução para próxima linha, que não é o que você quer, na prática uma chamada assíncrona.

O 2º argumento é um número de 0 a 10, com as seguintes intenções:

0. Hide the window (and activate another window.)
1. Activate and display the window. (restore size and position) Specify this flag when displaying a window for the first time.
2. Activate & minimize.
3. Activate & maximize.
4. Restore. The active window remains active.
5. Activate & Restore.
6. Minimize & activate the next top-level window in the Z order.
7. Minimize. The active window remains active.
8. Display the window in its current state. The active window remains active.
9. Restore & Activate. Specify this flag when restoring a minimized window.
10. Sets the show-state based on the state of the program that started the application.

---

Jahwakening!

Comment: Deu tudo certo muito obrigado pela sua ajuda